# Default parameter vs No Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have two methods as shown below. One with no parameters and one with only optional parameters.

```
void GetNext(){
   //implimentation
}

void GetNext(int currentindex = 0){
   //implimentation
}
```

Now which method will be invoked when a call is given to GetNext with no argument

```
 GetNext();
```

and why?

FYI : This has been asked in one of the interview.

Answer (score 2):

Method without optional parameter (`GetNext()`) is called. Answer why can be found in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx#Anchor_5):

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a
>   candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments
>   were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general
>   preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer
>   parameters.

Answer (score 0):

void GetNext() will be called, in this case the method with the optional parameter is hidden.
But if you call GetNext(1), GetNext(int currentindex = 0) will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Without parameter method `GetNext()` will be called

```
void GetNext(){
   //implimentation
}
```

because the preference is to call the without parameter method rather than the optional parameter overloaded method

**The Overload Resolution**

- A method, indexer, or constructor is a candidate for execution if each of its parameters either is optional or corresponds, by name or by position, to a single argument in the calling statement, and that argument can be converted to the type of the parameter.
- If more than one candidate is found, overload resolution rules for preferred conversions are applied to the arguments that are explicitly specified. Omitted arguments for optional parameters are ignored.
- If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters.